# RViz: backward-compatible?

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say I have a robot, running Indigo on Trusty, and a laptop, running Kinetic on Xenial. Would I be able to monitor the robot via RViz from the laptop?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245258/rviz:-backward-compatible?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2016-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this case I think it will work. However, you normally cannot assume comparability between distributions.

This is only possible because there were not so many changes between the two versions that affect rviz.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1